# How to change accessibilty settings in android phones?

Tags: android

I am thinking of making an app for android in which *if I select a word in any other app in android phone then a strip come above it*. In this strip there is a button named meaning if user click on this button, then its *meaning come as a pop-up* or in form of notification. These meaning will come from a database of dictionary which will be provided with app.

I just want to know how to change accessibility settings of phone so that if any word is selected anywhere in the phone, strip with meaning button come.

Comment: Your app must be signed with the same key used to sign the firmware Apps. As your requirement seems you want to make system app.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great idea, but I've never seen anything with that capability on stock androids--AFAIK, spell checkers are based in the OS, so I'd check those implementations out.
I'm doubtful that--as you describe it--it's even possible to do this in the traditional sense of apps, but would encourage you to look into the modding scene, where it is totally possible--consider cyanogenmod and the AOSP if you are interested in that sort of thing.

Love to be proven wrong on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a clipboard broadcast receiver:

[Create a clipboard receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500349/android-implement-broadcast-receiver-for-clipboardmanager)

Also have a look at this project as well.

[example project](http://code.google.com/p/my-clips/)

Also keep this in mind: Since there is now Action intent for clipboard, what you will need to do is create a broadcast receiver to start when your app is started on when the device first boots up. And then start a service to monitor the state of the clipboard.

Comment: Facing issue with creating virtual table. Please see this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618432/using-virtual-table-to-make-database-in-android]