# Excute if something's been copied

Tags: java, android, service, clipboard, foreground-service

In a foreground service I'd want to do this:
If the user copies something in any app, then use that text (in my case it'll be a url) for a function. I was wondering if there was a method to do something if the users has used the copy function.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500349/android-implement-broadcast-receiver-for-clipboardmanager